# WCF Web services and retrieving from a database - use existing asp.net service layer?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wcf, web-services, wcf-web-api

I've just started working on a WCF services project using web.api to expose data for a mobile version of our existing asp.net mvc web application.

So far I have used this [WCF web.api getting started tutorial](http://wcf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Getting%20started%3a%20Building%20a%20simple%20web%20api) to get something running, with fake data created in the ServiceContract.

The service contract looks like this:

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "")]
    public IQueryable<Workspace> Get()
    {
        //I want to use our existing service layer like this:
        //WorkspaceService service = new WorkspaceService();
        //service.ReturnAllWorkspacesByUsername("mary");

        //this is fake data for testing
        var workspaces = new List<Workspace>()
        {
            new Workspace() {Id = new Guid(), Title = "Implement WCF Web Services"},
            new Workspace() {Id = new Guid(), Title = "Add APIs to WebService"},
            new Workspace() {Id = new Guid(), Title = "Map Routes"},
            new Workspace() {Id = new Guid(), Title = "Expose Resources"},
        }; 
        return workspaces.AsQueryable();
    }
```

I would like to use the existing mvc application as much as possible, how can I use the existing service layer and domain model best, or is it best practice not to? Is it better to separate the services?

Can anybody point me towards some good beginner tutorials for this?

Thanks, 
Kai

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer to have a common in-process business logic layer. DTO (data transfer objects) are used to communicate across layers. When data access layer is based on EF, I prefer to use POCO entities as by DTOs. Now, for external applications or different UI, I build different service layers - it will use same in process BL and DTOs to get the data. However, I prefer to have a separate Data Contract classes for services.

Logic behind separation is that the BL layer API can be more chatty (being in-process layer) while service API will be based on state-less chunky interactions. You may expose limited functionality and/or different API via services (because underlying impression is that services will be used by external applications). Its also advisable to have DTOs & DataContract separate because both can change in different way and at different times. Data Contract changes has to be controlled and versioned while same may not be applicable to DTOs (or domain objects).

As far as your mobile UI goes, it need not use services but rather directly depend on in-process BL layer. This is possible if your original MVC application is a layered one.

Another observation - it does not make sense to return `IQueryable` from the WCF service. You can return an array of objects and client app can cast to `IQueryable` if needed.

Comment: Thanks :) I appreciate the reply. I think I will use the existing service layer as much as possible and do a bit or research on DTOs.